# Ubuntu 16.10 won't maintain resolution settings on 4k TV

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display-resolution, tv, 4k-monitor

I built an Ubuntu 16.10 PC, with a GTX 1080 card, and have it running into a new Sony 75" 4k HDR screen. I am running the latest Nvidia drivers.

**Problem:** the screen resolution defaults for 1920 x 1080. I can go into the Nvidia control panel and manually change it to 3840 × 2160, *and it works*, but after **every** reboot it falls back to 1920 x 1080. The biggest problem this makes for me is that I have to scale the UI up at 4k, and when it falls back to standard HD the interface is nearly too large to use.

I've tried some basic editing of the **xorg.conf** file, but it did not help. I should also say that the Nvidia control panel doesn't really identify my TV- it just says "**Sony *00**" or something like that. Perhaps I need an updated monitor profile?